# PL/SQL Cursor declaration issue?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am struggling to work through the error codes, but I assume its an issue with the declaration of the cursor. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
Create or Replace PROCEDURE project_sales_pp (percentequipmentincrease NUMBER,
percentcoffeeincrease NUMBER) AS
 pro_id         p.idproduct%type;
 pro_price      p.price%type;   
 pro_type       p.type%type;
 pro_quantity       bi.quantity%type;
 new_equip_total    NUMBER(10,4) := 0;
 new_coffee_total   NUMBER(10,4) := 0;
 new_overall_total  NUMBER(10,4) := 0;
 cursor newprofitcheckcursor IS 
 select p.idproduct, p.price, p.type, sum(bi.quantity) qty INTO pro_id, pro_price, pro_type, pro_quantity
 from bb_product p, bb_basketitem bi, bb_basket b
 where p.idproduct = bi.idproduct
 and b.idbasket = bi.idbasket;
 c_variables newprofitcheckcursor%rowtype;
BEGIN
 FOR c_variables IN newprofitcheckcursor loop
 IF pro_type = 'E' THEN 
 new_equip_total := new_equip_total + (pro_price * pro_quantity * percentequipmentincrease);
 end if;
 IF pro_type = 'C' THEN
 new_coffee_total := new_coffee_total + (pro_price * pro_quantity * percentcoffeeincrease);
 end if;
 end loop;
 new_overall_total := new_equip_total + new_coffee_total;
 dbms_output.put_line('Increase in equipment sales from a '||to_char(percentequipmentincrease)||' increase is '||to_char(new_equip_total));
 dbms_output.put_line('Increase in coffee sales from a '||to_char(percentcoffeeincrease)||' increase is '||to_char(new_coffee_total));
dbms_output.put_line('Total overall sales increase '||to_char(new_overall_total));
end;
/
```

Comment: What errors do you get and where?

Answer (score 0):

It would certainly help if you posted error message(s).

It is obvious that cursor's `select` statement misses the `group by` clause and shouldn't have `into` clause (you would need it if you executed that `select` out of a cursor):

```
CURSOR newprofitcheckcursor IS
    SELECT p.idproduct,
           p.price,
           p.TYPE,
           SUM (bi.quantity) qty
      FROM bb_product p, bb_basketitem bi, bb_basket b
     WHERE     p.idproduct = bi.idproduct
           AND b.idbasket = bi.idbasket
  GROUP BY p.idproduct, p.price, p.TYPE;                --> this
```

As I don't have your tables, I can't run your code so - if there are any other errors, please, say which ones.

---

As of wrong values you got: it is because you should have referenced cursor variable, not local variables. This is just one example; do the same for the rest:

```
  IF pro_type = 'E'
  THEN
     new_equip_total :=
          new_equip_total
        + (c_variables.price * c_variables.qty * percentequipmentincrease);
  END IF;
```

See the difference?

```
No : ... + (pro_price         * pro_quantity    * percentequipmentincrease);

Yes: ... + (c_variables.price * c_variables.qty * percentequipmentincrease);
```

Comment: I was able to fix the errors. I accidentally referred to the Pl/SQL variable types with the same abbreviation as I assigned in the cursor. Now they refer to their actual tables and it compiled. However, running the code is not accurately returning the numbers it should and is instead returning zeros in the DBMS output. Any suggestions? I also fixed and included the group by command.

Comment: @thenaa1  _"I was able to fix the errors. . . .  However, running the code is not accurately returning the numbers it should"_  So, first, we'd need to see the 'fixed' code.  And exactly what _are_ you seeing from the dbms_output? Are you getting all the text literals you specified?  Probably best to open a new question for this NEW problem.

Comment: Right; a closer look revealed another issues. I added some more info into the answer, have a look.

Comment: That seemed to do the trick. Ended up completely removing the local variables that were based on the attributes alone. Had to also change the variables for the IF condition to a %rowtype variable. I'll post the solved result as well.

Comment: You don't really need to declare c_variables.  Using it in the FOR..LOOP statement implicitly declares it for you.

Answer (score 0):

The old coded variables are left as a comment to see what needed to be removed. The local variables relating to the cursor were removed along with changing the variables in the if statements.

```
Create or Replace PROCEDURE project_sales_pp (percentequipmentincrease NUMBER,
percentcoffeeincrease NUMBER) AS
-- pro_id       bb_product.idproduct%type;
-- pro_price        bb_product.price%type;  
-- pro_type     bb_product.type%type;
-- pro_quantity     bb_basketitem.quantity%type;
 new_equip_total    NUMBER(10,4) :=0;
 new_coffee_total   NUMBER(10,4) :=0;
 new_overall_total  NUMBER(10,4) :=0;
 cursor newprofitcheckcursor IS 
 select p.idproduct, p.price, p.type, sum(bi.quantity) qty 
 -- INTO pro_id, pro_price, pro_type, pro_quantity
 from bb_product p, bb_basketitem bi, bb_basket b
 where p.idproduct = bi.idproduct
 and b.idbasket = bi.idbasket
 group by p.idproduct, p.price, p.type;
 c_variables newprofitcheckcursor%rowtype;
BEGIN
 FOR c_variables IN newprofitcheckcursor loop
 IF c_variables.type = 'E' THEN 
 new_equip_total := new_equip_total + (c_variables.price * c_variables.qty * percentequipmentincrease);
 end if;
 IF c_variables.type = 'C' THEN
 new_coffee_total := new_coffee_total + (c_variables.price * c_variables.qty * percentcoffeeincrease);
 end if;
 end loop;
 new_overall_total := new_equip_total + new_coffee_total;
 dbms_output.put_line('Increase in equipment sales from a '||to_char(percentequipmentincrease)||' increase is '||to_char(new_equip_total));
 dbms_output.put_line('Increase in coffee sales from a '||to_char(percentcoffeeincrease)||' increase is '||to_char(new_coffee_total));
dbms_output.put_line('Total overall sales increase '||to_char(new_overall_total));
end;
/
```